# How to make a command to launch a bash-script in mac terminal?

Tags: bash, automation, command

Basically, I want to be able to have a command for my command-line "Net", kinda like the "Python" command used to start python.

So I'd like to have a command like "Net" or something to start my bash-script, but I don't want to go into my .bash_profile and make an alias, I want it to be created automatically if you just run a script.

How would this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're looking for the install command...

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/install.1.html

```
install -m 755 ./my-bash-script.sh /bin/net
```

Just be sure use a directory that is in your $PATH and that you don't already have an executable file in your $PATH that is using the name of the command you plan to use.  'net' is an actual command used on linux systems, but I'm not sure about the Mac.

If you add it to your bash script, you might want to add some sanity checks...

```
#! /bin/bash
...
...
[[ ! -f /bin/$(basename $0) ]] && install -m 755 $0 /bin/$(basename $0)
```

Comment: Thanks. I've made a tool for installing my script now and it's working fine :)